# IOS Playing now button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to make a function like the Tunein App ( or other radio app ) when you select a Radio from a TableView you push the view to the Player and play the selected Radio showing in the ViewController the UIImage of the Radio and metadata of the song playing. 
This part is working perfectly but when I try to create the "playing now" button and push a view again using the following code, all the data was inside the view disappears.

```
 TvInternacionalViewController * detail = [[TvInternacionalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TvInternacionalViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
[detail release];
```

Is it way to save the data before leaving the ViewController and reload them when Pushing the View again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View controllers shouldn't store data.  Remember the model-view-controller (MVC) programming paradigm.  Store the data in a model object that both view controllers can access and then whenever your Now Playing controller loads, it just populates its views based on the model data.

Comment: Yes that fixed a part of my issue, but now when i am pushing the ViewController again the player play over the actual and for sure crash after some second... It look like I reloaded 2 ViewController !! What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code, but are instantiating the player in the view controller?  That may need to be abstracted out to another object so that the view controller is free to come and go as needed.